# Print the digits of a 3-digit number in order

Tags: python

I am currently trying to create a program that requests a 3 digit number from the user and prints out the individual digits of the number in order, eg:

```
"Input 3 digits: 123"
1
2
3
```

I am not allowed to use any form of strings, just mathematical operations.

Also, I have gotten formulas for the second and third digit but cannot get the first for the life of me, and when I run the program the first and the second digit return with a decimal number which I am not sure how to avoid.

My code:

```
n = eval(input('Enter a 3-digit number: '))
c = n % 10
b = n - c
b = b / 10
b = b % 10
a = n / b
a = a % 10
print(a)
print(b)
print(c)
```

Comment: Are you using Python 3 or Python 2?

Answer (score 2):

There's a much easier way to do this that doesn't require any math. In Python, strings are iterable and `input()` returns a string. So you can just do this:

```
n = input('enter a number: ')
for x in n:
    print(x)
```

Comment: @JoeDingle So it's a completely different question from what you actually asked?

Answer (score 1):

Divide your number by 100, inside of a call to `int`:

Input 3 digits: 435

`firstDigit = int(n / 100)`

firstDigit will be 4

Comment: Thank you! I can't believe I didn't figure that out

Answer (score 1):

You get the input as a string so, using your example, you would get '123'.
If you're not obligated to use the formulas, you could get each digit as follows:

```
user_input = input('Enter a 3-digit number: ')
first_digit, second_digit, third_digit = [int(digit) for digit in user_input]
print first_digit
print second_digit
print third_digit
```

Answer (score 0):

THe problem is where you divide n by b -- no reason to divide the original number by its second digit. You probably wanted to divide by 10 again.

It's easier if you remember that when you divide *integers*, you get an integer -- so, for example:
    329 / 10
gives
    32
That save you from having to subtract at all (also, clearer variable names make it much more readable):

```
dig3 = n % 10
n = n/10
dig2 = n % 10
dig1 = n/10
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this:

```
n = eval(input('Enter a 3-digit number: '))
c = n % 10
b = int(n / 10)
b = b % 10
a = int(n / 100)
a = a % 10
print(a)
print(b)
print(c)
```